# XML Parsing remote server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I have followed some tutorials on how to **parse** XML from remote websites and came across the wonderfully articulated question and answer in stackoverflow. 
However even after following the question, following program is not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Aviation</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var result;
function xmlparser() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://services.faa.gov/airport/status/IAD?format=xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) { 
            result = $(xml).find("City").text();
            document.myform.result1.value = result;
        },
        error: function (xml) {
            alert(xml.status + ' ' + xml.statusText) ;
        }
    });             
}        
   </script>    
   </head>
   <body>
   <p id="details"></p>
   <form name="myform">
   <input type="button" name="clickme" value="Click here to show the city name" onclick=xmlparser() />
    <input type="text" name="result1" readonly="true"/>        
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The website which I am trying to parse is same.

[US FAA](http://services.faa.gov/airport/status/IAD?format=xml)

Also I want to develop it as stand alone application i.e. Just HTML interacting with the remote website.

Comment: can't do cross domain xml ajax when api not CORS enabled. Read up on `same origin policy`

Comment: you can use jsonp from the same api: http://services.faa.gov/airport/status/IAD?format=json&callback=alert

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, you can (need to) use jsonp because faa.gov apparently forgot to add the appropriate header to their API responses.
By the way - always prefer json over xml with Javascript - it's so much nicer to work with.

```
// ask faa.gov to add the HTTP header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" to their response
// then you can use this
// jQuery.getJSON('http://services.faa.gov/airport/status/IAD?format=json');

jQuery.ajax({
  url: 'http://services.faa.gov/airport/status/IAD?format=json',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function (data) {
    document.myform.result1.value = data.city;
  }
});
```

Comment: For some reason only Washington coming while I click the button. Do you know why ?

Comment: Well, I don't know what you are trying to do or expecting to get returned. In the URL, "IAD" stands for "Washington Dulles International" airport. If you replace it with "LAX" for example, you get the city "Los Angeles". You need to change the request URL to get different cities.